# Prevent jQuery Mobile from toggle on listview item when dragged

Tags: jquery, mobile, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, collapsable

I have a jqm listview in which there are collapsible sections, and want all list elements to be draggable (sortable to be precise) http://jsfiddle.net/aaTAJ/20/.

After collapsible list item is dropped its content is toggled, and that's what I want to get rid of.

So far I have:

```
 jQuery('ul').sortable({
    revert: 50,
    axis: 'y',
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    opacity: 0.75,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        window.preventCollapsibleToggle = true;

    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        window.preventCollapsibleToggle = false;
    }
})
```

which requires modifications in jqm core:

```
...
collapsible.bind("expand collapse", function(event) {
if (!event.isDefaultPrevented() && !window.preventCollapsedToggle) {

    event.preventDefault();

    /* ... */

}
}).trigger(o.collapsed ? "collapse" : "expand");
```

It's working, but if its possible i'd rather not to change jqm core.

Anyone has better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line

```
revert: 50,
```

seems to do the job: http://jsfiddle.net/aaTAJ/33/

Also, [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) states that "revert" is a boolean.